# $\sigma$ strong topology and *-operation continuity

Tags: operator-theory

I know that if H is an infinite Hilbert space then *-operation is not continuous with respect to the $\sigma$ strong topology. Now, I have a question. If H is finite dimension, is *- operation continuous with respect to the $\sigma$ strong topology? Why? please help me

Answer (score 2):

Any operator topology (including norm topology) is a vector topology since all of them are generated by seminorms. All vector topologies coincide on finite dimensional spaces, so in finite dimensional case it is enough to prove continuity of $^*$-operation with respect to any of the operator topologies. Clearly $^*$-operation is continuous with respect to the norm topology for any Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: Furthermore, any real-linear transformation (from one finite-dimensional space to another) is continuous.